# ColorBox JS being applied to external JS loading

Tags: jquery, colorbox

be have a lander that loads external javascript after the user performs certain actions. As the classes are loaded after the actions are taken, colorbox does not work on these classes. Is there a way to bind colorbox to classes that are loaded after full page load?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code so that it launches after page is loaded:

```
$(document).load(function () {
    // your code here
    // eg. Set classes for colorbox
});
```